# Django queryset models through an intermediate model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a a model `Meeting` that is related to `Signup` which in turn is related `Attendee`.
Models:

```
class Meeting(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False)

class Signup(models.Model):
    meeting = models.ForeignKey(Meeting, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    ...

class Attendee(models.Model, PrintNameTag):
    signup = models.ForeignKey(Signup, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="attendee")
    attendee = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=200)
    ...
```

How do I make a queryset on Meeting.objects that will also return the other fields in Signup and Attendee?  I need all data for a report.  I'd prefer not to change my models because this seems like this should be doable the way they are.  I'd also like to query Meeting because I have some other stuff in the query that Meeting is needed for (removed for simplicity).

Here's what I currently have:

```
qs = Meeting.objects.filter(id__in=queryset).prefetch_related('signup').annotate(attendee_signup=F('signup__attendee_signup'))
```

I keep getting "cannot resolve keyword attendee_signup into field"

I also have tried variations of:

```
qs = Meeting.objects.filter(id__in=queryset).select_related('signup').filter(attendee__signup=signup_id)
```

I get "name 'signup_id' is not defined"

I'm brand new to python and Django and I don't know if I need to use F and/or annotate, prefech_related or select_related.  I've looked up what each does, but I can't find the right syntax to get this working.  I feel like I've tried every combo and I'm just mashing keys at this point.  Could someone help please?

Comment: please get rid of the A,B,C and post your actual model code.

Comment: Edited to show my models

Comment: Are you trying to fetch each signup and each attendee for a meeting? BTW how is Signup and Attendee different? Aren't they sort of modelling the same thing?

Comment: Right, I need all Signups and Attendees for a Meeting.  Signup has other fields like the company name, address, etc.  But a Signup can have up to 6 Attendees.  The Attendees model tracks each attendee from a company, their name, lunch option, if they attended, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add `related_name='signups'` to the `Signup.meeting` field, then this *should* work:

```
meetings = Meeting.objects.filter(id__in=queryset).prefetch_related('signups__attendee')
```

The above will fetch all meetings, and all signups for those meetings, and all attendees for those signups. From there you can iterate over everything and it will all have already been fetched from the database:

```
for m in meetings:
    for s in m.signups:
        for a in s.attendee:
            # whatever
```

(Incidentally, I would recommend changing that `related_name` from "attendee" to "attendees" as the plural form tends to be more intuitive.)